# Checking Valid Next Position for Maze ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, path-finding

Alright so I've been trying to make this path-finding algorithm to search through a maze, and I've run into a problem that seems near trivial, but I haven't found an elegant solution.

This method is supposed to check which spaces are valid to be tested in a later method.

So the error occurs at the edge positions because its checking for a space that is outside the double character array. Is an earlier check necessary to determine if its null? Or will I need to add a bunch of ifs that check if it is row[0] or column [0] (or both!) and adjust accordingly?

Say this is the maze: (0 = empty, traversable space, 1 = wall)

```
01010
01000
00010
01110
```

```
public static boolean[] isValidPath(char [][] maze, Position current){
    int currentRow = current.i;
    int currentColumn = current.j;

    boolean[] intersection= new boolean[4];
    //[right, down, up, left]
    //In order of priority to get to bottom right

    //right
    intersection[0] = (maze[currentRow][currentColumn+1] == '0');
    //down
    intersection[1] = (maze[currentRow+1][currentColumn] == '0');
    //up
    intersection[2] = (maze[currentRow-1][currentColumn] == '0');
    //left
    intersection[3] = (maze[currentRow][currentColumn-1] == '0');

    return intersection;
}



Error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
0 1 0 1 0
at PathFinder.isValidPath(PathFinder.java:73)
0 0 0 1 0 
at PathFinder.stackSearch(PathFinder.java:154)
0 1 0 0 0 
at PathFinder.main(PathFinder.java:47)
0 1 0 1 1 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
0 1 0 0 0 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Post your entire exception with stack trace.

Comment: Please add this info (by using [edit]) to your question.

Comment: Make a `getTile(row, column)` that returns the item at the coordinates or `1` if outside. Then you can call that instead of adding checks on each array reference

Comment: Not every position has 4 adjacent ones. You need to control your borders.

Comment: Yeah I get I need to control the borders, its just how to do it. Is there a "safe way" like a compareTo() method that won't throw an error and will just default to false?

Comment: getTile is interesting. I think that could work. I'm not sure how to handle it when it gets a null value though.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant solution: insert the maze into a larger maze (+1 on each side) with all edges as walls and only check the original maze positions

e.g.
1111111
1010101
1010001
1000101
1011101
1111111

Comment: This would cause another set of problems due to other already functioning methods

Comment: If so you can do the whole insertion inside isValidPath and scrap it when you're done.